# Combining array of objects with common values and return a key and value for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

```
 [
{id: 68, name: "IT"}
{id: 67, name: "IT"}
{id: 66, name: "Supply chain"}
{id: 65, name: "Manufacturing Engineering"}
{id: 64, name: "Sales & Marketing"}
{id: 63, name: "Research and Development"}
{id: 62, name: "Research and Development"}
{id: 61, name: "Research and Development"}
]
```

Please any means to achieve this below?. I want to pass it to select option to get respective id and names

```
[ {
1: IT
2: Supply Chain,
3: Research and Development
}]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your input and expected output? Your example output seems to 1) Exclude "Manufacturing Engineering" and "Sales & Marketing" 2) Doesn't seem to use the same set of id values. Is that intentional? I am assuming the code block at the top is your input.

Comment: This is my expected output, 
[{id: 1, name: "IT"}
{id: 2, name: "Supply chain"}
{id: 3, name: "Manufacturing Engineering"}
{id: 4, name: "Research and Development"}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following gets you the output you want, but I suspect there are other factors it might not be accounted for (e.g. maintain IDs, sorting, etc...).

Given:

```js
const input = [
    {id: 68, name: "IT"},
    {id: 67, name: "IT"},
    {id: 66, name: "Supply chain"},
    {id: 65, name: "Manufacturing Engineering"},
    {id: 64, name: "Sales & Marketing"},
    {id: 63, name: "Research and Development"},
    {id: 62, name: "Research and Development"},
    {id: 61, name: "Research and Development"},
];
```

We can:

```js
const output = [...new Set(
    // Get a unique set of department names
    input.map(i => i.name)
)].map(
    // With the new set of department names
    // Reconstruct the list with id values starting at 1 instead of 0
    (dept, idx) => ({
        id: idx + 1,
        name: dept,
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it only gave me this 0: {id: 1, name: Array(57) }. It groups all the names together with one ID, and the names are not unique.

Comment: @Francis in that case, your input format must not match your example provided in your initial post. Can you try to provide us with `JSON.stringify(input);` to ensure we're working off the correct input. You can also try using the input definition I provided and see if it matches the format you have.

Comment: "data": [
        {
            "id": 68,
            " name": "IT",
            },
{
            "id": 67,
            " name": "IT",
        },
{
            "id": 66,
            " name": "Supply",
        },
{
            "id": 66,
            " name": "Manufacturing",
        },

]... This is the data format returned from my API

Comment: Okay. Two observations. 1) Your "name" key has a space prefix within the string. If that is accurate, `i.name` in the answer above will need to be adjusted to `i[" name"]`. 2) Your API response is wrapped in a data object. You need to be sure to call the map on the data array. So `apiResponse.data.map(i => i.name)`. See https://jsfiddle.net/7o2jgpce/ for a working end-to-end example.

Comment: Thank you, i solved it with your illustration, it really helped me

Comment: Great, please go ahead and accept the answer if you got what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use rxjs, you can use this solution.

```
  this.data = [...] // array

  from(this.data)
    .pipe(
      distinct(data => data.name),
      map(data => data.name),
      toArray(),
      map(names => ({...names}))
    ).subscribe(
      console.log
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, you can make use of `Map` to first filter out the duplicate value then mapping it accordingly. here is how:

```js
var data = [{id: 68, name: "IT"},{id: 67, name: "IT"},{id: 66, name: "Supply chain"},{id: 65, name: "Manufacturing Engineering"},{id: 64, name: "Sales & Marketing"},{id: 63, name: "Research and Development"},{id: 62, name: "Research and Development"},{id: 61, name: "Research and Development"}];

var result1 = [...new Map(data.map(val=>[val.name, val])).values()];
var result2 = [...new Map(data.map(val=>[val.name, val])).values()].map(({id, name},i)=>({id:i+1, name}));

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2);
```